# Generating OpenAM tokens for a user

Tags: openam, opendj

Let's say I have two applications, appA and appB. appA has a simple database authentication approach and appB uses ForgeRock's OpenAM. I want a user in appA to be able to SSO into appB. Because the username/password in appA is different then the creds in OpenDj, I'm wanting to add a column to my user table in appA called external_user_id. I would then use this to generate a token to hand over to appB. I'm curious if there is a way in OpenAm to generate tokens for a user using only their username and not their password. If there was the idea of a serviceAdmin account that lets appA generate tokens based on just a username, that would be awesome, but I'm doubting that something like this exists. Is there something like this in OpenAM that I'm missing?

Comment: Really I'm just wondering if there is a way in OpenAM to generate a token for a user from a different Admin type user account.

Comment: Presumably OpenAM would need some level of trust for appA?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to tackle this kind of a situation is to write a custom authentication module that would receive a session ID or a "secret" from appA, then validate it and issue a new session on the OpenAM domain, and thus giving access to appB.